# JUnit 5 and inheritance with different extensions for Spring Boot Integration test with TestContainers

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, junit5, testcontainers

**Intro:**
Our product needs to have integrations tests for 3 different databases:

1. Oracle
2. Postgres
3. MSSQL

We are using Spring Boot as our framework and TestContainers to start up the databases mentioned above.

**The problem:**
We need to run the same tests for each container (database).

After a lot of digging on the net the only way that I could think of was using a BaseClass where we write all the test cases and for each container, we create a class that inherits from the BaseClass and we override the method and annotate it with @Test.

Below in the code, you will a single JUnit5 extension for Postgres that starts a TestContainer, base test class, and a test class that gets extended from the Postgres extension, starts a Spring Application context, and runs the tests from the base class.

The code:

```
import com.company.itest.AutoConfig;
import com.company.itest.BaseIntegrationTest;
import com.company.itest.db.mssql.MSSqlTest;
import com.company.itest.db.oracle.OracleTest;
import com.company.itest.db.postgres.PostgresTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

public class TestTheTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {
  public void contextLoads() {
    Assertions.assertEquals(1, 1);
  }
  public void contextLoads2() {
    Assertions.assertNotEquals(1, 2);
  }
}


@SpringBootTest(
    classes = AutoConfig.class,
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@PostgresTest
class TestPostgres extends TestTheTest {
  @Test
  public void contextLoads() {
    super.contextLoads();
  }
  @Test
  public void contextLoads2() {
    super.contextLoads2();
  }
}


import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;

public class PostgresqlTestContainersExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {

  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostgresqlTestContainersExtension.class);

  private PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres;

  @Override
  public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) {
    log.info("Setting up postgres container");
    postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:13").withReuse(true);

    postgres.start();
    System.setProperty("spring.datasource.url", postgres.getJdbcUrl());
    System.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", postgres.getUsername());
    System.setProperty("spring.datasource.password", postgres.getPassword());
  }

  @Override
  public void afterAll(ExtensionContext context) {
    postgres.stop();
  }
}



package com.company.itest.db.postgres;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Target({TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ExtendWith({PostgresqlTestContainersExtension.class})
@Testcontainers
public @interface PostgresTest {}
```

**The question:**

How can I create a single JUnit test class and then rerun it with a different JUnit5 extension without doing this polymorphism?

Comment: You could implement an interface with the tests in default methods instead of extending a superclass. That’s still a polymorphic approach though. For a small number of variations, like 3 different databases, I find this approach acceptable.

Comment: I also worked with similar problem. You should start your test 3 times with different parameters instead of trying start once and rerun 3 times

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven, you could try to have a different profile per db